# Multiple transaction synchronization factories in the same flow

Tags: transactions, spring-integration

I have the following flow: a SFTP inbound streaming adapter reads a file, which is a JSON. Then:

- a transaction synchronization is registered directly on that adapter to rename the input file on transaction commit (because I've done with it)
- the file that was read is converted into a DTO with the `json-to-object` and thrown to a transformer which transforms it to something else
- this "something else" should be put on another channel, but only after transaction commit

This is the essence of the flow:

```xml
<int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter
  session-factory="mySftpSessionFactory"
  channel="channel1"
  filename-pattern="*.JSON"
  remote-directory-expression="'/mypath'"
  max-fetch-size="10">
  <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-delay="1"
    time-unit="MINUTES" error-channel="unexpectedErrorChannel">
    <int:transactional
      synchronization-factory="synchFactory1"
      transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </int:poller>
</int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="synchFactory1">
  <int:after-commit channel="onCommitRemoteFileRenameChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int:channel id="channel1" />

<int:chain input-channel="channel1" output-channel="nullChannel">
  <int:stream-transformer charset="UTF-8" />
  <int:json-to-object-transformer type="com.example.MyDto" />
  <int:transformer ref="myTransformer">
    <int:transactional synchronization-factory="synchFactory2"
      transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
  </int:transformer>
</int:chain>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="synchFactory2">
  <int:after-commit channel="onCommitSecondFlowChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int:channel id="onCommitRemoteFileRenameChannel" />
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway
  session-factory="mySftpSessionFactory"
  request-channel="onCommitRemoteFileRenameChannel" 
  command="mv"
  expression="headers[T(org.springframework.integration.file.FileHeaders).REMOTE_DIRECTORY].concat('/'.concat(headers[T(org.springframework.integration.file.FileHeaders).REMOTE_FILE]))"
  rename-expression="headers[T(org.springframework.integration.file.FileHeaders).REMOTE_DIRECTORY].concat('/'.concat(headers[T(org.springframework.integration.file.FileHeaders).REMOTE_FILE].concat('.done')))"
  requires-reply="false"
  reply-channel="nullChannel" />
```

The second `<int:transactional>` declared inside the transformer is not meant to actually open a new transaction (the default propagation should be REQUIRED, so it should join the main transaction opened by the poller), but rather to just add a second synchronization that fires the message returned by the transformer to the channel named `onCommitSecondFlowChannel` for further processing.

However, this seems not to work properly: while the remote file renaming is performed correctly, the second synchronization is not applied, since I do not get any message obtained from the trasnformer into the `onCommitSecondFlowChannel`.
I tried to debug and I see that both `<int:transacationl-synchronization-factory>`s are parsed, but the second one's method `ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor.processAfterCommit(IntegrationResourceHolder)` is never executed.

Is there a way I can obtain this result without declaring a service activator and a gateway after the transformer to place the message on that second flow channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating your flow with that extra tx-sync.
It is realy was not designed to do something in the middle of the flow.
It is rather some global hook from the point where we start transaction. Since you don't in that transformer, therefore it cannot be applied.

We may revise it in the future since I see your feeling and it is really logical that such a tx-sync should join existing TX if cannot start a new one at this point.

Anyway I wouldn't do that since it makes the flow not intuitive.

I see you have this `<int:chain input-channel="channel1" output-channel="nullChannel">` - `nullChannel` as an output after that `<transformer>`.

So, how about to remove that `<transactional>` altogether and place `onCommitSecondFlowChannel` as an output for this `<chain>`? Anyway it looks like this is the end of your flow therefore no need to defer something to the end of transaction.

Comment: Thanks Artem for your insight. Well, the first version of the flow was indeed the one you describe, but the downstream flow involves multiple separate transactions: putting `onCommitSecondFlowChannel` on chain output brings a "tx was set to rollback only" if one such tx rolls back, because the poller (outer) tx is joint. So I tried a dispatcher to break the poller tx boundary, but then I have optimistic locking exceptions because both flows change the same entities too close from each other. Hence the idea to serialise the flows (it's fine if the second is executed only when the first commits)

Comment: I'll then add a service activator after the transformer which calls a gateway to the second flow after transaction commit: it's some code I would prefer to avoid, but it seems to be necessary.